# Convergence of: $\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left(2-x^{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}} \text{ where } x>0 $

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need determine about convergence of series below. I applied Raabe's test but without success.I think it was because the sequence is not more than zero for every $n$. There is a hint to use  Gauss's test but I am not very familiar with that. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

$$\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\prod_{k=1}^{n}{\left(2-x^{\frac{1}{k}}\right)}} \space, \space x>0 $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gauss' test tells you that for a series $S = \sum a_m$, if the successive term ration can be expressed as 
$$
\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} = 1 - \frac{p}{n} + \frac{B(n)}{n^r}
$$
for some real value $p$, real $r > 1$, and bounded function $B(n)$, then $S$ converges (absolutely) if and only if $p>1$.

Let's apply this to our series.

First off, when $0<x\leq 1$, each term in the products is at least $1$, so each $s_i$ is at least $(2-x^{1/1}) > 1$, so the series obviously diverges.

Now consider $1 < x < 2$. Here, $\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} = (2-x^{1/(n+1)})$. 
Taylor expand for large $n$ to get

$$\frac{s_{n+1}}{s_n} = 1 - \frac{\log x}n + \frac1{n^2}\left( 
\log x - \frac12 (\log x)^2 - \frac{\log x - (\log x)^2+\frac16 (\log x)^3}{n} 
\\+ \frac{\log x -\frac32 (\log x)^2+\frac36 (\log x)^3+\frac1{24} (\log x)^4}{n^2}{n^2}+ \cdots \right)
$$
The function in parentheses on the right is clearly bounded as each term past the first two will be some power of $\log x$ divided by higher and higher powers of $n$.  So the Gauss condition is met with $p = \log x$.  Since $1<x<2 \implies \log x < 1$,  $S$ converges in that range of $x$.

For $x=2$ of course $S$ converges to zero because the first term in each product is zero.

For $2 < x < e$, the value $p=\log x < 1$ so the series converges.

Finally, for $x \geq e$ the Gauss test has $p \geq 1$ and $S$ diverges.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive and helpful answer I need time to understand better.

Comment: I was thinking about it and it works cool but i am sure that series converges for x=2 and x>e depending on what you wrote about Gauss's test.